Raise the Dead rote
How can a Raise the Dead spell can be performed in Mage the Ascension? Considering the dead the zombie-like creature from medieval fantasy settings, with no mind, but able to follow simple commands, like "fight" or "follow them" at the command of the mage.
Would it need quintessence to perform and mantain the spell? How many corpse would be able to be raised?

Vampire
Have Path of Bones •• Apprentice’s Brooms. Raise Zombies.
Mage
I found 3 canon rotes that create undead servants. Spending Quintessence is not mandatory, but might make it easier.

Reanimation - (•• Spirit, or •• Forces,
•• Matter, and •• Prime -
Tradition Book: Euthanatos, (Revised) p.66

Spirit 2 would force a spirit into a corpse to talk to them. But we want an animated corpse, that's the Forces Matter Prime Version of this Rote. This rote gives our zombie a strength score and the ability to move, and to follow your commands.

The Key of Vanth - •• Forces,
•• Matter, and •• Prime - Dead Magic 2 (Revised) p. 144

Like the one above - which is essentially a reprint of - this rote creates undead servants. As a slight revision, it explicitly requires 4 successes to raise a corpse as an undead. This is the only rote I found that raises more than one undead, if you have extra successes.

Hear and Obey - ••••• Spirit, •••• Life, or ••••
Life, •••• Mind - Book of Crafts, (1st Edition) p.26

This rote not only raises a zombie or skeleton, it works entirely different: first it traps the soul that used to inhabit it and destroys it mostly (spirit 5 or mind 4), and the body is forced to follow all commands of the person holding the locket (life 4). This is the real Voodoo Zombi experience, the creature created is very much smart, and technically not dead.

Would you mind to explain the differences within a rote? I see at least 2 of them can be performed with different set of Spheres, I wonder if they have different results. Can you add it to your answer?

@BrunoEstrazulas the first 2 are essential reprints of one another.
